# Post multiple data from an loaded form ajax mvc 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form like this

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tên học sinh </th>
                    <th>Giáo lý viên </th>
                    <th>Năm Học</th>
                    <th>Điểm TB Học Kỳ 1 </th>
                    <th>Điểm TB Học Kỳ 2 </th>
                    <th>Điểm Tổng Kết Năm Học </th>
                    <th>Lớp </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <fieldset class="form-horizontal">

                    <tbody id="addDetails">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("HocSinhId", String.Empty)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HocSinhId, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("GiaoLyVienId", String.Empty)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GiaoLyVienId, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NamHoc)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NamHoc, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DiemTBHK1)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiemTBHK1, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DiemTBHK2)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiemTBHK2, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DiemTongKetNamHoc)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DiemTongKetNamHoc, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownList("LopId", String.Empty)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LopId, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "AddDetails", new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                OnSuccess = "successCall",
                                @*UpdateTargetId = "addDetails",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,*@

                            })
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6">
                                @*<a  href="#"> </a>*@
                                <input type="submit" value="Lưu thông tin" class="button" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                </fieldset>
            }

        </table>
```

After click Ajax link "Add" it will insert new row to input new data.

Image: http://i808.photobucket.com/albums/zz1/nquangkhaiDST/Postmultipledata_zps5364f0a0.png

**The Question is**: *When I submit to server, it just post the first data, not the data after i click "Add". How i can get all the data even field from ajax to post back to server.*

Anyone know how to post all the data even the data of ajax. Thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll be adding that same type of object when you click `Add`, what you need to do is accept an array of your model object in your Post controller parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(MyObject[] objects) 
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: But it is'not post all the data, it just post the original form. Every data from ajax not included

Answer (score 0):

did you check your html on client side.... while submitting from client side you have to make sure that that the controls added on the page must have naming convention like

```
<input type="text" value="" name="IncomeDetails[0].IncomeCode" id="IncomeDetails_0__IncomeCode" class="incomeCode valid" disabled="disabled">
```

on the first row and

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" class="incomeCode valid" id="IncomeDetails_1__IncomeCode" name="IncomeDetails[1].IncomeCode" value="">
```

on the second row then only while submitting you can get full list of objects.